# FastApi + Gunicorn workers + Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-multithreading, fastapi

I'm deploying a sample fast api app to the cloud with google standard app engine model. The app is served with gunicorn this way:

`gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:80`

This command spawns 4 worker proccesses of my app.

I've read that in fast api you can either create sync or async endpoints. If an endpoint is async all requests run on a single thread with the event loop. If the endpoint is sync, it runs the function on another thread to prevent it from blocking the server.

---

I have sync blocking endpoints, so fastapi should run them on threads, but also i have gunicorn spawning worker proccesess.

Given that python only executes one thread at a time, but also the standard app engine is also limited CPU wise on multiple proccessing, i'm confused on the best configuration for a fastapi application on the cloud.

Should i let gunicorn or fastapi handle the concurrency?

Comment: Hi OP, let us know if the answer helped you. If not, please leave a feedback so we can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

The number of workers you specify should match the instance class of your App Engine app; and since you're using 4 workers in your app, it has an equivalence of `4 instance classes`. Here's an example that shows an App Engine deployment that uses `4 gunicorn` workers for serving apps: `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 -w 4 main:app`. The examples I've provided was stated in the [entrypoint best practices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices).

Just a note, the `gunicorn` uses sync workers by default so that worker class is compatible with all web applications, but each worker can only handle one request at a time.

Lastly if using Google App Engine Flex, kindly check the [recommended gunicorn configurations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#recommended_gunicorn_configuration) for further guide in your app.